# cron command with server configration not working at all

Tags: php, cron

I have created following command line to run cron job after every 2minutes

```
 2 * * * *  php -f /home/u260451427/public_html/cron/cron_sms_sending_queue.php
```

my sever configuration look something like that [image: cron_job]

but its not working.

Comment: Assuming you've tested the program via web browser, your program could be working, but, the code may not be written to work in a CLI environment. If you have lynx/links installed, try this variant: `lynx -source http://localhost/cron/cron_sms_sending_queue.php > /dev/null` Of course, replace localhost with whatever web address that's supposed to be, make sure lynx/links is installed, and so forth. This would bypass any environment differences between web and CLI that might prevent the program from working.

Comment: The time specification says to run once per hour, at two minutes past; not once per two minutes. Perhaps there is a bug in the crontab GUI you are using. Linux/Vixie cron supports `*/2` for running every two minutes, but this is not available on some other platforms.

Comment: Why not `curl` or `wget -O /dev/null`? Both are more common than lynx etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2 * * * *  <command>` will run every 2nd minute past every hour.

From 'man 5 cron':

```
Step values can be used in conjunction with ranges...
Steps are also permitted after an asterisk, so if you 
want to say ``every two hours'', just use */2
```

Therefore your crontab entry should be

`*/2 * * * * <command>`